# Telerik Metro XAML Windows 8 chart controls and bindings

Tags: xaml, charts, telerik, windows-runtime

I am building an app that uses Windows 8 Metro XAML preview controls. I have downloaded and examined the sample app, but it mostly uses code-behind to define all the stuff necessary for the charts. I am trying to accomplish something similar with bindings, and the charts remain empty. Actually, they get the data, but plot nothing (for example, I can see the borderline of the RadPieChart and all zeroes for RadCartesianChart). Here is the code for RadPieChart:

```
<telerik:RadPieChart>
    <telerik:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding AssetsData}" />
</telerik:RadPieChart>
```

And AssetsData is defined like this:

```
private ElementCollection<PieDataPoint> assetsData;
public ElementCollection<PieDataPoint> AssetsData
{
    get
    {
        return assetsData;
    }
    set
    {
        assetsData = value;
        Notify("AssetsData");
    }
}
```

Filled with data, like this:

```
PieSeries series = new PieSeries();
series.RadiusFactor = 0.9;

foreach (var entry in dataSource)
{
    series.DataPoints.Add(new PieDataPoint() { Value = entry.Percentage, Label = entry.Title });
}

assetsData = series.DataPoints;
```

Everything works fine when I use code-behind (C#) like in the sample app. I define the series, add the datapoints to series and add that series to chart control. When using the same data and trying to bind like this, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

I checked if the values in the collection are set properly, and they are (since I'm using the same logic as when I use code-behind, there shouldn't be any difference really, and there isn't).

Also, is there a way to set RadCartesianChart to scale it's minimum and maximum according to the data that's being drawn?

Comment: I've never used RadPieChart, so I can't solve your problem, but I think you might have better luck at the Telerik forum.

Comment: Thanks, I tried there too, but since it's a preview version, I don't know if I'll get support from them. So any help here is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

I also struggeled with the controls, and it wasn't untill I realized that you have to define the palette programmatically that I managed to get the charts to show me anything. At the moment I've got this example, but next week I'll work on the charts some more and I can post some better code for you. But this might at least get you started!

```
            <Grid Height="520" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="#007EA9" Height="auto" Width="500">
            <Border Background="#007EA9">
              <telerik:RadCartesianChart x:Name="barChart" Margin="0,6,0,0" Height="250" Width="230">
                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                  <telerik:CategoricalAxis LabelFitMode="MultiLine">
                    <telerik:CategoricalAxis.LabelStyle>
                      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="10" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
                      </Style>
                    </telerik:CategoricalAxis.LabelStyle>
                  </telerik:CategoricalAxis>
                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                  <telerik:LinearAxis Maximum="200" Minimum="0">
                    <telerik:LinearAxis.LabelStyle>
                      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                      </Style>
                    </telerik:LinearAxis.LabelStyle>
                  </telerik:LinearAxis>
                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
                  <telerik:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility="Y" />
                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
              </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
            </Border>
          </StackPanel>
          <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Height="auto" Width="500" Margin="0,35,0,0">
            <Border Background="#007EA9">
              <telerik:RadPieChart x:Name="pieChart" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="250" Width="230" />
            </Border>
          </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

C# code

```
        private void CreateSuckyChart()
    {
        double value;

        pieChart.Palette = ChartPalettes.DefaultDark;
        barChart.Palette = ChartPalettes.DefaultDark;

        var data = new List<WBDataEntry> { new WBDataEntry { Data = "Benchpress", Value = 70 }, new WBDataEntry { Data = "Squats", Value = 15 }, new WBDataEntry { Data = "Lat pulls", Value = 205 }, new WBDataEntry { Data = "Lunges", Value = 55 } };
        var series = new BarSeries();
        series.CategoryBinding = new PropertyNameDataPointBinding("Date");
        series.ValueBinding = new PropertyNameDataPointBinding("Value"); 
        this.barChart.Series.Add(series);
        var series2 = new PieSeries();
        var labelDefinition = new ChartSeriesLabelDefinition();
        labelDefinition.Margin = new Thickness(-10, 0, 0, 0);
        labelDefinition.DefaultVisualStyle = this.Resources["PieChartLabelStyle"] as Style;
        series2.LabelDefinitions.Add(labelDefinition);
        series2.RadiusFactor = 0.7;
        series2.AngleRange = new AngleRange(-90, 360);

        this.pieChart.Series.Add(series2);

        foreach (WBDataEntry indicator in data) // Class WBDataEntry has two properties, Value and Date
        {
            series2.DataPoints.Add(new PieDataPoint() { Value = indicator.Value, Label = indicator.Data });

            series.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint() { Value = indicator.Value , Label = indicator.Data });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have something similar, I've been using my palette and everything worked fine when defined in C#, but not when I try to do databinding...

Comment: Next week I'll be working on my charts and I will be using databinding as well, once I get it working you'll be the first one to know. If you succeed before me, please post the answer here and save me some trouble instead ;) Let's see who solves this one first :D

Comment: Hi Daniela, the guys from Telerik helped me out and it worked! See their answer here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/community-forums/about-telerik/metro-xaml-charts-and-binding.aspx

They even attached a sample project! Great support. ;)

I hope it'll help you too!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've found the solution, but I thought I'd post a solution here. Here's my xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <t:ChartPalette x:Key="CustomPalette">
            <t:ChartPalette.FillEntries>
                <t:PaletteEntryCollection>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"></SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"></SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Purple"></SolidColorBrush>
                </t:PaletteEntryCollection>
            </t:ChartPalette.FillEntries>
            <t:ChartPalette.StrokeEntries>
                <t:PaletteEntryCollection>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"></SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"></SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Purple"></SolidColorBrush>
                </t:PaletteEntryCollection>
            </t:ChartPalette.StrokeEntries>
        </t:ChartPalette>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <tpri:RadLegendControl LegendProvider="{Binding ElementName=pieChart}">
        <tpri:RadLegendControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </tpri:RadLegendControl.ItemsPanel>

        <tpri:RadLegendControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Fill}" Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="10" Height="10"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{Binding Fill}"  Margin="10" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </tpri:RadLegendControl.ItemTemplate>
    </tpri:RadLegendControl>

    <t:RadPieChart x:Name="pieChart" Palette="{StaticResource CustomPalette}">
        <t:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ScoreCard}" RadiusFactor="0.8">
            <t:PieSeries.ValueBinding>
                <t:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Total"/>
            </t:PieSeries.ValueBinding>

            <t:PieSeries.LegendTitleBinding >
                <t:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Name"></t:PropertyNameDataPointBinding>
            </t:PieSeries.LegendTitleBinding>
        </t:PieSeries>
    </t:RadPieChart>
</Grid>
```

For the ScoreCard binding, I have this:

```
private ObservableCollection<TestQuestionResult> _scoreCard;
public ObservableCollection<TestQuestionResult> ScoreCard
{
    get { return _scoreCard; }
    set { _scoreCard = value; Notify("ScoreCard"); }
}
```

The data class looks like this:

```
public class TestQuestionResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Correct { get; set; }
    public int Incorrect { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

This method generates dummy data for testing:

```
private void Init()
{
    var list = new ObservableCollection<TestQuestionResult>();
    var ran = new Random(-1);

    for (var ix = 0; ix < 7; ix++)
    {
        var tq = new TestQuestionResult()
        {
            Name = ix.ToString(),
            Correct = ran.Next(321, 932),
            Incorrect = ran.Next(321, 932),
        };

        tq.Total = tq.Correct + tq.Incorrect;
        list.Add(tq);
    }

    ScoreCard = list;
}
```

I hope this saves others at least the time I spent on it. :)